# gulp-awspublish with AWS profile instead of AWS_ACCESS_KEY and secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp, nuxt.js

I am trying to deploy my nuxt static website to S3 using this guide.
https://nuxtjs.org/faq/deployment-aws-s3-cloudfront

The deployscript works when using which I tried an a personal AWS account:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="key"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secret"

It does not work when unsetting these exports and using the AWS_PROFILE export on a separate AWS account. On this AWS I am not able to get an access key and secret because of company policy.

I also use these AWS profiles for other things so I am sure they are configured properly.

The error I am getting in the console is:

> Error: Connect EHOSTUNREACH <EC2 IP address???>

The part in brackets is the IP address I am seeing. Which is weird where it tries to connect to EC2 since the script works on S2 and cloudfront.

The script I am using

#!/bin/bash

```
export AWS_PROFILE="profile_name"
export AWS_BUCKET_NAME="example.com"
export AWS_CLOUDFRONT="UPPERCASE"

# Load nvm (node version manager), install node (version in .nvmrc), and npm install packages
[ -s "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" ] && source "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" && nvm use
# Npm install if not already.
[ ! -d "node_modules" ] && npm install

npm run generate
gulp deploy
```

As for the gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const awspublish = require('gulp-awspublish')
const cloudfront = require('gulp-cloudfront-invalidate-aws-publish')
const parallelize = require('concurrent-transform')

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html

const config = {
  // Required
  params: {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME
  },
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    signatureVersion: 'v3'
  },

  // Optional
  deleteOldVersions: false, // NOT FOR PRODUCTION
  distribution: process.env.AWS_CLOUDFRONT, // CloudFront distribution ID
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
  headers: {
    /* 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=315360000, no-transform, public', */
  },

  // Sensible Defaults - gitignore these Files and Dirs
  distDir: 'dist',
  indexRootPath: true,
  cacheFileName: '.awspublish',
  concurrentUploads: 10,
  wait: true // wait for CloudFront invalidation to complete (about 30-60 seconds)
}

gulp.task('deploy', function () {
  // create a new publisher using S3 options
  // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#constructor-property
  const publisher = awspublish.create(config)

  let g = gulp.src('./' + config.distDir + '/**')
  // publisher will add Content-Length, Content-Type and headers specified above
  // If not specified it will set x-amz-acl to public-read by default
  g = g.pipe(
    parallelize(publisher.publish(config.headers), config.concurrentUploads)
  )

  // Invalidate CDN
  if (config.distribution) {
    console.log('Configured with CloudFront distribution')
    g = g.pipe(cloudfront(config))
  } else {
    console.log(
      'No CloudFront distribution configured - skipping CDN invalidation'
    )
  }

  // Delete removed files
  if (config.deleteOldVersions) {
    g = g.pipe(publisher.sync())
  }
  // create a cache file to speed up consecutive uploads
  g = g.pipe(publisher.cache())
  // print upload updates to console
  g = g.pipe(awspublish.reporter())
  return g
})
```

The gulp-awspublish docs mention it should be possible to connect with an AWS profile by adding it to the export (which I do in my deploy file).

They also mention using the aws js sdk which I also tried by integrating following snippet.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
 
var publisher = awspublish.create({
  region: "your-region-id",
  params: {
    Bucket: "..."
  },
  credentials: new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: "myprofile" })
});
```

When I use the export aws_profile it does at least seam to authenticate. When using the SDK I receive an error mentioning

> CredentialsError: Missing Credentials in config, if using
> AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

Where adding the latter (AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1) to my deployment script does not make any difference.

**Any Idea if I a missing something in the script to make it work?
My user policies where set as mentioned in the tutorial. Maybe they forgot something?**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::example.com"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation",
        "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
        "cloudfront:ListInvalidations",
        "cloudfront:UnknownOperation"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since awspublish uses the javascript sdk I needed to `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true` which solved the issue!